# Tiny black bugs eating holes in my plant’s leaves

Tags: insects, bugs

There are tiny black bugs that are eating the leaves of the vegetables in my garden. They seem to be attacking the cabbage, arugula, kale, but not the peas. Any idea what they are or how to get rid of them? Thank you so much! [image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably flea beetles, they love brassica crops. Depends what part of the world you're in as to which ones you've actually got - they tend to attack seedlings, so  it's best to provide row covers to keep them off.  Later, waxy or curly leaved crops like cabbage or kale are less attractive to them, but still somewhat vulnerable. Assuming you're in USA, further information here https://ag.umass.edu/vegetable/fact-sheets/flea-beetle-brassica